# Would it be faster to use a for loop or list out the operations?

Tags: c

I'm working on code to do matrix operations for a satellite my school is making. Would it be faster and less resource intensive to use a for loop or to just write out the operations? All matrices are of a known size

```
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)//Row
{
    for (j = 0; j < 3; j++)//Column
    {
        result[i][j] = a[i][j] * b;
    }
}
```

or

```
result[1][1] = a[1][1] * b;
result[1][2] = a[1][2] * b;
etc...
```

Comment: With such microoptimization, the best way to find out usually is to measure yourself. The answer may depend on the sizes of the matrix, your compiler ,and many other variables. Make a program that runs the code in question a few million times and then time the execution of both versions.

Comment: I'd prefer the `for` loops because it's much more readable and easier to understand. Also, because it avoids repetition. That being said, modern compilers will optimize the code so I doubt if your unrolled version will have any performance impact at all

Comment: Even if the manually unrolled version is slightly faster, it probably doesn't matter.

Comment: The only way to know is to code up both versions and measure their performance on the target system.  If the matrices are only 3x3, then the difference will be negligible..  If they were more like 3000x3000, then you may see a measurable difference, but you're not going to manually unroll 3000x3000 operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are talking about loop unrolling. You're right, it is a common technique to decrease computing time of a program. However, as it has been said in the comments, it is not absolutely sure you will save time, because it depends on many factors (compiler, compiler optimisation level, etc...). It is also possible that the compiler does unroll loops itself if you choose a high optimisation level.

Don't forget it takes more code size, which is also a valuable resource.

Keep in mind there are other ways to optimize code. For example here, you multiply all elements in an array by the same variable. Perhaps you can do this multiplication later in the code when you access again the `result`array ? It will save travelling an array with all the memory accesses it implies.